# Can Watson generate the most possible sentence according to a given words?

Tags: ibm-watson

Given a list of English words, synthesise the most probably English sentences, which
 are grammatically correct, and which bear the common concept among this words.
E.g.:
a) "water", "hands" -> "I would like to wash my hands".

b) "salad", "eat"     -> "I would like to eat a salad".

c) "time", "now", "question" -> "What is the time now?".

d) "pizza", "vegan", "order"  -> "I would like to order a vegetarian pizza".

if there is a number of probable sentences, as to propose a few candidates.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting request. I don't think there is a Watson REST API that will do exactly what you are requesting. Did you notice that 2 of the examples you give have verbs which you interpret in the infinitive, and two that don't have verbs. In your problem scenario do verbs have to be provided or not? Your examples are very clear cut, where the meaning is most likely to be what you suggest, but what about "water", "glass".

The closest match would be the dialog service. The dialog service you can create input handlers that are looking for keywords, or variants in a submitted phrase. The downside is that, although a Pizza ordering dialog will be able to interpret "pizza", "vegan", "order", it normally wouldn't be able to handle "time", "now", "question".

Next up would be the natural language classifier service. It works the other way round from your suggestion, in that it looks for intent, so needs the key words "I would like" and "What is" to derive the intent behind the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

As @chughts said, the problem here is that this could only make sense if you have a very big corpus of text data full of phrases, like for example, Google has for Google Search (and then Google suggests phrases using autocomplete). However, I don't believe that's the way Watson works. (sorry, I don't know how Watson works internally).

That said, Watson can answer questions if you tell it how to map questions to answers. Dialog component can really do that, because you can set an initial set of answers and tell Watson to extrapolate from these "seeds" to recognize a broader set of questions (because you can always ask "how are you?" or "how are you today?" or "how are you feeling today?" or "how exactly are you feeling today, pal?". But again, using the Dialog component, you're actually providing the corpus of questions.